# Service injected into spring controller is not available in one of the functions

Tags: java, spring, rest, dependency-injection, controller

I am writing spring controller, which injects a bean.

The bean is added in config(we use java config for everything):

```
@Bean
public NotificationService notificationService() {
    return new NotificationService();
}
```

The service itself has few injected dependencies and few functions:

```
public class NotificationService {

    @Inject
    NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

    @Inject
    ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Inject
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public NotificationDto create(NotificationDto notificationDto) {
        //convert to domain object, save, return dto with updated ID
        return notificationDto;
    }

    public void markAsRead(Long id, String recipientNip) {
        //find notification, update status
    }
}
```

Model mapper has almost no configuration, is only set to strict. Meanwhile repositoriers are interfaces extending `JpaRepository` with no custom functions. They are found by `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Finally I have controller that tries to use the code above:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationController extends ExceptionHandlerController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('create_notification')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaTypeExtension.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createNotification(@Valid @RequestBody(required = true) final NotificationDto notification) {
        this.notificationService.create(notification);
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('update_notification')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/read", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    private ResponseEntity<?> markNotificationAsRead(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @AuthenticatedContractor ContractorDto contractor) {
        this.notificationService.markAsRead(id, contractor.getNip());
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

All controllers are added trough @ComponentScan, based on their package.

As you can see both functions use `notificationService`. When I send `POST` for `create` on `/notifications` the `notificationService` is properly injected. In the same controller, when I do `PUT` request on `/{id}/read`, the `notificationService` is `null`.

I think it has something to do with spring putting things into its container, and for some reason not being able to do it for that one function. I have few more functions in the controller and in all of them `notificationService` is properly injected. I don't see any real difference between `createNotification` and `markNotificationAsRead` functions and I couldn't find anything even remotely related on google/stack. In all cases the service wouldn't inject at all because of configuration mistake.

**Edit**
I have tried changing things around in the function until it has started working. My final code looks like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('update_notification')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}/read", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> read(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @AuthenticatedContractor ContractorDto contractor) {
        this.notificationService.markAsRead(id, contractor.getNip());

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and it works. Honestly I can't see any difference from my original code, and I have been staring at it for last hour or so. The imports are the same too.

I have also noticed(on unworking code) that while all functions from the controller on debug stack were marked as

```
NotificationController.functionName(arguments) line: x
```

The non working function was:

```
NotificationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64d88bfe(NotificationController).‌​markNotificationAsRead(ContractorDto) line: 86
```

Why this single function was enhanced by spring CGLIB I have no idea. I have tried looking it up, but for now I came empty handed. Even though the code started to work I am leaving the question open in order to find the underlying cause.

Comment: Are you sure it's `notificationService` is `null`, not `contractor` at the same line?

Comment: 100% sure. Contractor is properly filled in the debug. Also, evaluating contractor.getNip() returns proper value.

Comment: It simply cannot be `null`, your controller is a singleton (at least normally it is!) if it fails for one method it will fail for all methods. It has nothing to do with your function.

Comment: Try declaring a constructor for `NotificationController`, which takes the `NotificationService` as a parameter (and which checks that it's not null), assign it the the field (which should be `final`) and put `@Autowired` on the constructor.  Then you'll be guaranteed by Java that the field is non-null, and if Spring's not injecting it properly then you'll find out up-front instead of when you try to make the REST call. Autowired non-final fields look nice and simple, but go rather against the grain of best-practice Java.

Comment: I have tried doing what skaffman suggested, but it didn't help. I have noticed that in other functions in the controller the place where code is stopped on debug stack is called NotificationController.functionName(arguments) line: x, while in the not working function it's NotificationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64d88bfe(NotificationController).markNotificationAsRead(ContractorDto) line: 86

I tried googling EnhancerBySpringCGLIB, but I don't know why and how it works in this case. Also, please read update in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method `markNotificationAsRead` is private and that probably causes the issue. I've just had same issue with final method - this message appeared in log:

```
2016-11-28 17:19:14.186  INFO 97079 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Unable to proxy method [public final java.util.Map com.package.controller.MyController.someMethod(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
```

Looks like in one case we see a CGLib proxy, and in another - the actual class. Only one of those has all the fields injected, looks like the proxy has all fields nulls. But it doesn't matter - the point is your method should be public and not final in order to be proxied properly by @PreAuthorize methods.

Comment: We have done something different since then to work around the issue, but I checked on old commit and it works. Gosh, so simple, yet so hard to spot.

Comment: Yes. The "INFO" level for this log message is a weird choice.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. It was all due to the private access modifier used and  @PreAuthorize. Making the controller method private does not make an issue if you do not make it secure. But, to make secure, make it public.